# How to change the values in a column in large data set without replacement

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset partially look like the following:

```
m1    m2  m3   m4
jp-1  1    2   3
jp-2  2    9   8
jp-4  2    4   4
jp-8  3    2   1
jp-7  1    4   4
jp-9  2    4   0
jp-3  2    4   4
jp-6  3    1   5
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

There are about `100000` rows for each column, and I want to delete `"jp-"` from the column `m1`. I check this question online but many of the solutions are to replace the column with a new values, that is not what I want. What I want is the following, just to delete `"jp-"` from `m1`.

```
m1   m2  m3   m4
1    1    2   3
2    2    9   8
4    2    4   4
8    3    2   1
7    1    4   4
9    2    4   0
3    2    4   4
6    3    1   5
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: `sub("^jp-", "", df$m1)`

Comment: "many of the solutions are to replace the column with a new values, that is not what I want. What I want is the following, just to delete "jp-" from m1." -- I don't think this is a meaningful distinction in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sub` function to remove the prefix `jp-` and overwrite the content of your column. If `d` is your data:

```
d$m1 <- sub("jp-", "", d$m1)
```

**EDIT:**

if you want to make the column of class `numeric`, you can add `as.numeric`:

```
d$m1 <- as.numeric(sub("jp-", "", d$m1))
```